# Ruby on Rails link generated with link_to helper no longer works in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

Chrome has been making a lot of changes recently, and one of them has broken a code statement I use to retrieve a document stored in a database, related to a parent record. The action to upload the file and create the attachment relationship is working, so my users can still add documents. They can no longer download and view stored document attachments. The code is using the link_to helper method, and appears to be building the link correctly, verified by the fact that it still works using Edge, so my users have an ugly workaround, but I need to understand what is happening. I have confirmed that it is indeed Chrome that is the problem, because at first I couldn't recreate the defect in development (until I updated my Chrome browser to current version.) Now I can recreate the defect in my development environment.

When the link in my form is clicked, Chrome displays an error screen with this text:

```
This page isn't working
(*localhost*) sent an invalid response
net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

If I extract the link using developer tools and try and execute it in an empty browser window, I get the same error.

The link is constructed like this:

```
<a href="/attachment/(*record-key-value*)/(*name-of-the-file attachment*)">(*name of the file attachment*)</a>
```

Before you ask, yes, I have confirmed there are no commas or quotes in my file names! lol

I am hoping someone somewhere can point me to a solution, hopefully simple, maybe obvious, that I can use to get my web form to play nicely with Chrome again - application code change, web server configuration (I am running on RHEL7 Apache in production and Puma in development, my database is Oracle, and I am building with Ruby 2.3.6 and Rails 5.1.5, along with many many gems).

I hope I have covered all the relevant points. Thank you for taking the time to read this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by upgrading gem attach to version >= 1.0.5. Many thanks to the gem author for excellent responsiveness.